# Kotlin error when fetching API with RxJava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

So I'm new to kotlin, and I'm trying to fetch API with RxJava by following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VObSnk5jrpc&list=PLRRNzqzbPLd906bPH-xFz9Oy2IcjqVWCH&index=6

But I got an error saying:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
```

Here is the code:

```
try {
            compositeDisposable.add(
                apiService.getMovieDetails(movieId)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(
                        {
                            _downloadedMovieDetailsResponse.postValue(it)
                            _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.LOADED)
                        },
                        {
                            _networkState.postValue(NetworkState.ERROR)
                            Log.e("MovieDetailsDataSource", it.message) //this is where the error is (the it.message)
                        }
                    )
            )
        }

        catch (e: Exception){ 
            Log.e("MovieDetailsDataSource",e.message) //this is where the error is (the e.message)
        }
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

```
e.message!!
```

The Problem will be solved

Comment: With this code, if the Exception doesn’t have a message, then another exception will be thrown and not caught. Safer to use `e.message.orEmpty()`.